# How to keep off MultiPageEditor with StructuredTextEditor to show Outline View for all pages?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a multi-page XML editor for eclipse and using a `StructuredTextEditor` for the first page. I am wondering if is it possible to let the outline view show contents only if the text editor is selected. While the selection is one of the other pages the outline view shouldn't show anything.

I add the text editor to the multi-page editor as follows:

```
private StructuredTextEditor textEditor;

@Override
protected void addPages()
{
    textEditor = new StructuredTextEditor();
    addPage(textEditor, getEditorInput());

    // add other pages
}
```

I also declared a content type in `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
     <content-type
         id="artFile"
         name="%content-type.name"
         base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
         file-names="app_registration_template.vm"
         file-extensions="vm">
         <describer class="org.eclipse.core.runtime.content.XMLContentDescriber"/>
     </content-type>
</extension>
```

How can I now control the Outline view?

Comment: Well your editor has complete control of the content outline view so you can do what you want. What have you coded for `IContentOutlinePage`.

Comment: Nothing. I use the available implementation of `IContentOutlinePage` of the `StructuredTextEditor`, this should be `org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.contentoutline.ConfigurableContentOutlinePage` The other pages don't have any implementation of `IContentOutlinePage` and this is ok since I don't want to have any view for the other pages. But the view isn't getting updated on the page change.

Comment: The content outline view code does not know anything about multi-page editors and only supports one content outline per editor.

Comment: @greg-449 Your statement actually proved useful in order to create a workaround for this problem.

Comment: @DannyLo I added a GIF image for demonstration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

As mentioned by @greg-449 in the question's comments "The content outline view code does not know anything about multi-page editors and only supports one content outline per editor."

This is true and actually gave me an idea of how to tackle with the problem. The solution that I came up with is related with refreshing the outline view(closing and open it again programmatically) while you navigate among tabs.

So to begin with, I applied the solution in a multipage editor that combines EMF/GMF tabs as well as a StructuredTextEditor for displaying XML.

## What you should already have

Your multipage editor should Override/add the following methods. Note that, this is not a plug & play situation, search on how to create a custom outline page or how to call the default outline page based on the editorInput. The reason I am adding this is for understanding.

---

*(pay attention to the showOutlineView method) It returns false because we want to disable the other views. However, you could offer different outlines per editor if you wish. To do that you will need always return true in the showOutlineView and initialise differently the outline page in the getContentOutlinePage() method. Possibly by having different implementation of the page based on the editor requested.*

---

```
/**
 * This is how the framework determines which interfaces we implement.
*/
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public Object getAdapter(Class key) {
    if (key.equals(IContentOutlinePage.class)) {
        return showOutlineView() ? getContentOutlinePage() : null;
    } else {
        return super.getAdapter(key);
    }
}

/**
 * This accesses a cached version of the content outliner.
 */
public IContentOutlinePage getContentOutlinePage() {
    if (contentOutlinePage == null) {
        //your outlinepage from your editor
        //or create a custom page(s)
    }
    return contentOutlinePage;
}

/**
 * Returns whether the outline view should be presented to the user.
 */
protected boolean showOutlineView() {
    //e.g if StructuredTextEditor xmlEditor;
    //like this we force the editor getAdapter contentOutline part
    //to return false, and therefore the contentoutline will get a value of
    //null that results in "an outline in not available" in the outline view
    if(getActiveEditor() != xmlEditor)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

## How to apply the solution

In order to apply the solution you will need to modify the **pageChange** method as well as introduce a method that refreshes the outline view programatically and call it appropriately.

```
public void refreshOutlineView() {
    //get the activePage
    IWorkbenchPage wp =  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    //Find desired view by its visual ID
    IViewPart myView=wp.findView("org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline");

    //Hide the view :
    wp.hideView(myView);
    try {
      //show the view again     
      PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("org.eclipse.ui.views.ContentOutline");
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

@Override
protected void pageChange(int pageIndex) {
    refreshOutlineView();
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

## What the solution does/ How it does it

The outline view of an editor is initialised while the editor is initialised (e.g when you open a file with the editor). After that point it's retrieved and it does not change due to caching. Now what this workaround does is to close the outline view programmatically (so as to force an initialization call). When this call is made we can then initialise and display the outline view of our preference.

---

Right click on the gif - open in new tab to view it

---

[image: Gif demonstrating the solution]